# Camera not working on work profile - Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, camera, xamarin.essentials, android-work-profile

I've developed an app using Xamarin for android devices. I am using the media picker from the Xamarin.Essentials package. In my place of work we have two types of devices - one has a work profile side, that uses Microsoft intunes. The application runs fine of the other devices but crashes when I open the camera on the device with the work profile. I have asked for the relevant permissions in the manifest. Does anyone have any experience with this? This is my first time using Xamarin. I've included part of my code below and the error it throws.

Kind Regards

```
bool x = MediaPicker.IsCaptureSupported;
            if(x == false)
            {
               await DisplayAlert("ok", "alert", "cancel");
            }
            var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();

            var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();

            newImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
    
     

      java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3827)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4003)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2317)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8595)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy (FileProvider.java:606)
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy (FileProvider.java:579)
  at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile (FileProvider.java:417)
  at crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.IntermediateActivity.n_onCreate (Native Method)
  at crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.IntermediateActivity.onCreate (IntermediateActivity.java:31)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8207)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8191)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1309)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3800)
```

UPDATE:
I think I may need to request permissions for the app to access the camera that is on the work profile? Is this possible

Comment: What exception is it throwing in the case when it fails, I have intunes in my premises as well yet this never happened with me, it could be a different issue altogether. Add your exception into the question, if possible also add the relevant stacktrace.

Comment: Hi I've added the stack trace. I don't get an exception thrown it simply crashes.

Comment: There is an exception being thrown that's why it crashes. Put the relevant code in a [try catch block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) and add breakpoint to the catch block, in the exception object you will get a stack trace post that, the one you have posted above isn't enough to tell you what or where the crash is coming from

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs I realised the issue is probably because of the thread.

When you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android) it clearly says:

> All methods must be called on the UI thread because permission checks and requests are automatically handled by Xamarin.Essentials.

So the code you are using to get the photo should look something like below :

```
 var photo = await Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.
            InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(
            async () => await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync());
```

This means your full code would look like this:

```
bool x = MediaPicker.IsCaptureSupported;
        if(x == false)
        {
           await DisplayAlert("ok", "alert", "cancel");
        }
       var photo = await Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.
            InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(
            async () => await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync());
        var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();

        newImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

Also it's kinda weird this code works on your other device!

Comment: Hi, no unfortunately this did not work. I think it is something to do with a file URI but I've very little experience with that?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?